# Доставать значение textarea при клике на ячейку

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp

[image: xtar]

Имеется 75 ячеек в таблице. При клике на любую из них мне надо достать значение которое находится в textarea этой ячейки. 
 id ячеек пронумеровано от 0 до 75, знаний в js нет, и не знаю как при клике на div ячейки доставать значение её textarea

Comment: Не знаю как логика эта реализуется, нужно onclick или что-то привязывать в тэги или вообще через css реализовывать, не понимаю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так используя библиотеку Jquery

После нажатия в консоль выведет значение textarea.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>

<table style="width:100%" id="table">
  <tr>
    <th id="1"><textarea class="text">text 1</textarea></th>
    <th id="2"><textarea class="text">text 2</textarea></th>
    <th id="3"><textarea class="text">text 3</textarea></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th id="4"><textarea class="text">text 4</textarea></th>
    <th id="5"><textarea class="text">text 5</textarea></th>
    <th id="6"><textarea class="text">text 6</textarea></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th id="7"><textarea class="text">text 7</textarea></th>
    <th id="8"><textarea class="text">text 8</textarea></th> 
    <th id="9"><textarea class="text">text 9</textarea></th>
  </tr>
</table>


<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('.text').click(function(event) {
            console.log($(this).val());
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

***Решение на чистом JS***

Логика простая: есть ячейка таблицы с уникальным id, внутри каждой ячейки textarea с одиннаковым классом

Кликаем по ячейке, получаем её id, достаем из этого елемента дочерний textarea с уже известным именем и получаем значение

HTML:

```
<table style="width:100%" id="table">
  <tr>
    <th id="1"><textarea class="text">text 1</textarea></th>
    <th id="2"><textarea class="text">text 2</textarea></th>
    <th id="3"><textarea class="text">text 3</textarea></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th id="4"><textarea class="text">text 4</textarea></th>
    <th id="5"><textarea class="text">text 5</textarea></th>
    <th id="6"><textarea class="text">text 6</textarea></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th id="7"><textarea class="text">text 7</textarea></th>
    <th id="8"><textarea class="text">text 8</textarea></th> 
    <th id="9"><textarea class="text">text 9</textarea></th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
function findValue(e) {
    var tableCell = e.target;
    var textArea = tableCell.childNodes.getElementsByClassName('text');
    console.log(textArea.value);
}

var tableCell = document.getElementById("table").childNodes.getElementsByTagName("th");
tableCell.addEventListener("click", findValue, false);
```

Comment: У меня здесь 5 разныы table, не знаешь, как реализовать? Что-то не получается у меня, все что ты написал скопировал, но в js не шарю

Comment: Код скопировал, но что-то не выводит мне textarea, не знаю почему :(

Comment: @Timka можно посмотреть где-то полный код страницы который получился?